# Best Practice for multiple queries in exception report

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on creating an exception report that will look for issues across the database and display in in a dashboard.

Things like 5 files where Date of Birth is missing, 
2 files where Age is greater than 100 years, 10 clients with status Open and a file close date exists...

really an unlimited number of exceptions.  I'm hoping to put each possible exception into a table, along with the select query required to generate the data.

The web design would then be an alert box that shows all the non-zero exceptions found.

What would be the most efficient way to go about doing this in SQL Server?

Comment: Hire a developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are new to sql. Thats fine
Create a table for exceptions and select the data from the table which ever has an exception. For example you can have a query as,

```
 INSERT INTO EXCEPTION_TABLE
       SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME 
       WHERE DOB IS NULL OR
             AGE > 100 OR
             .......   OR  ----------- add all your exception possiblities
             .......
```

Comment: Hope you got it. Any issues let me know, will help you

Comment: Certainly more helpful (and appropriate) than ajeh's comment

Comment: Thank you for the response and that is sort of where I am right now.  I was reading about prepared statements - this was mysql centric though
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496

Comment: Would it be feasible to have a table with headings: Exception    Query then data DOD Null,"Select * from Clients..."

so that the maintenance of the exceptions and associated queries can be done in a separate interface.

I wasn't planning on making the table full of exceptions public so not too worried about injection, but there are a lot of them, and wanted to make the back end less cluttered.